# progress information and PartNumber of async Amazon S3 multi-part upload

Tags: c#, asynchronous, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 using multi-part uploads using [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html). I have changed the `List<UploadPartRequest>` to `List<Task<UploadPartRequest>>` that I then call `Task.WaitAll(myList.ToArray)` on when it's full.

The only thing is, when I add the progress event to each `UploadPartRequest` object, I am unable to figure out which part is giving me back information (as they all feed back at the same time!). I can do the uploads synchronously and track the PartNumber currently being uploaded, but this isn't ideal, as it's obviously much slower.

Does anybody know how I can get the `PartNumber` of the `UploadPartRequest` during the asynchronous upload? Being honest, it really doesn't look like it (the `StreamTransferProgressArgs` doesn't have the info and seems the only way to do it), but I thought I'd throw out this net and see what I catch...

**Update**

Here's my code snippet:

```
private void MultiPartUpload(string localUNC, string destinationUNC)
{
    var uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();
    var initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
    {
        BucketName = _bucket,
        Key = destinationUNC
    };

    var response = _s3.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest);
    var contentLength = new FileInfo(localUNC).Length;

    try
    {
        long filePosition = 0;
        for (TotalParts = 1; filePosition < contentLength; )
        {
            TotalParts++;
            filePosition += PartSize;
        }

        filePosition = 0;
        for (CurrentPart = 1; filePosition < contentLength; )
        {
            var uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
            {
                BucketName = _bucket,
                Key = destinationUNC,
                UploadId = response.UploadId,
                PartNumber = CurrentPart,
                PartSize = PartSize,
                FilePosition = filePosition,
                FilePath = localUNC
            };

            uploadRequest.StreamTransferProgress += 
                new EventHandler<StreamTransferProgressArgs>(OnPartUploadProgressUpdate);
            uploadResponses.Add(_s3.UploadPart(uploadRequest));
            filePosition += PartSize;
            CurrentPart++;
        }

        var completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest()
        {
            BucketName = _bucket,
            Key = destinationUNC,
            UploadId = response.UploadId
        };

        var completeResponse = _s3.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error during multi-part upload: {0}", e.Message);

        var abort = new AbortMultipartUploadRequest()
        {
            BucketName = _bucket,
            Key = destinationUNC,
            UploadId = response.UploadId
        };

        _s3.AbortMultipartUpload(abort);
    }
}
```

and the delegate function is:

```
    private static void OnPartUploadProgressUpdate(object sender, StreamTransferProgressArgs e)
    {
        //var obj = sender as AmazonS3Client;

        //if (obj != null)
        //{
            Console.WriteLine(
            "Part: {0} of {1} - {2:0.00}/{3:0.00}MB uploaded. {4}% complete.",
            CurrentPart,
            TotalParts,
            ConvertByte.ToMegabyte(e.TransferredBytes),
            ConvertByte.ToMegabyte(e.TotalBytes),
            e.PercentDone);
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(
        //        "{0}/{1}MB uploaded. {2}% complete.",
        //        ConvertByte.ToMegabyte(e.TransferredBytes),
        //        ConvertByte.ToMegabyte(e.TotalBytes),
        //        e.PercentDone);
        //}
    }
```

The `ConvertByte` class is my own creation. I've left in the commented out code so you can see what I've tried.

Comment: Isn't the `sender` parameter of the event handler the `UploadPartRequest` it belongs to? Try casting it and then accessing its `PartNumber`.

Comment: No. That object is the `AmazonS3Client` object, which (I think) is useless in identifying which part is being uploaded. It's very frustrating, and it really feels like either I'm missing something simple or Amazon have messed up something simple...

Comment: In that case, I think the best solution would be to use a lambda. If you post your code (I don't quite understand how exactly did you modify that sample), I could show you what exactly do I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the event handler be a lambda, that can access the `uploadRequest` local variable:

```
uploadRequest.StreamTransferProgress +=
    (_, e) => OnPartUploadProgressUpdate(uploadRequest, e);

…

static void OnPartUploadProgressUpdate(
    UploadPartRequest request, StreamTransferProgressArgs e)
{
    var partNumber = request.PartNumber;
    …
}
```

Comment: That worked a charm! Feeling frustrated that I didn't think of that, though. Ah well. You live and learn!